# How to split strings with regex without first and last special character

Tags: python, regex

I'm having trouble using regex.

So basically I have this kind of string :

```
string = '<bash><exit><bash-trap><terminology>'
```

What I would like to have in the end is a list of all separate words :
['bash', 'exit', 'bash-trap', 'terminology']

What I've done so far :

`substitution = re.sub(r'[^A-Za-z0-9-]+', ' ', string)`

then

`re.split(r'[^A-Za-z0-9-])',substitution)`

Which gives me the following result :

`['', 'bash', 'exit', 'bash-trap', 'terminology', '']`

Thanks !

Comment: `print(re.findall(r"\<(.*?)\>", string))` ?

Comment: Your regex isn't that bad. You can simply call `substitution.split()` after your first `re.sub`.

Comment: Or add a [`strip`](https://www.journaldev.com/23625/python-trim-string-rstrip-lstrip-strip#:~:text=strip()%3A%20returns%20a%20new,string%20with%20trailing%20whitespace%20removed.&text=lstrip()%3A%20returns%20a%20new,left%E2%80%9D%20side%20of%20the%20string.) before the `split`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you want is a list of words inside angle brackets. So, you can use `re.findall` directly on the input string.

```
re.findall(r'<(.*?)>', string)
```

Code:

```
import re

string = '<bash><exit><bash-trap><terminology>'    
print(re.findall(r'<(.*?)>', string))
# ['bash', 'exit', 'bash-trap', 'terminology']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use pattern `\<(.*?)\>`

**Ex:**

```
import re

string = '<bash><exit><bash-trap><terminology>'
print(re.findall(r"\<(.*?)\>", string))
# --> ['bash', 'exit', 'bash-trap', 'terminology']
```